# Fetching json content from a git diff command result

Tags: git, github, diff, github-cli

```
Git diff tag1.2 tag1.5
```

Output for the above command is

```
**Tag
Some character
@@262728
{
'Code-version':'1.5',
'changes':[
'code-repo':'2.1']
}
**Tag
Some character
@@262728
{
'Code-version':'1.4',
'changes':[
'code-repo':'2.0']
}
**Tag
Some character
@@262728
{
'Code-version':'1.3',
'changes':[
'code-repo':'1.9']
}
```

I need to display only the latest json content like below excluding other unwanted stuffs

```
{
'Code-version':'1.5'
'changes':[
'code-repo':'2.1']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the content of a file at a specific tag (or commit), you can use [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show):

```
git show tagname:path/to/file
```

`git diff` shows the difference between *two* revisions of a file, but you are only interested in one specific version of the file.